# Syntax highlight issue for C variables starting with uppercase letter

Tags: support, syntax-highlighting

The syntax highlighter works well, in most cases. But there's one point that irks me.

In C programs, the highlighter gives variables that start with an uppercase letter a different colour.

See [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/135718/184981) for instance, where the name `Aa` is displayed in cyan instead of black like the other identifiers.

[image]

Or even better, [this lovely answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11000897/1016716) (as long as that one doesn't get edited into something sensible).

[image]

Sample:

[image]

Now for languages like C#, this might make sense, because all of the .NET API is title-cased, so you can distinguish between system identifiers and local identifiers this way, presuming that local identifiers are lowercase. In C however, none of the libraries have title-cased words, and this distinction doesn't make sense.

So, can this be corrected?

Comment: that is correctly highlighted as lang-c so as Ernest suggested, I recommend reporting that to the Google Prettify folks

Comment: The [post you're referring to](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11000897) can easily be fixed by using `<pre></pre>` instead of the spaces. Furthermore, in this case, the `>` (quote) has to be used instead, because it's a [citation](http://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/linux/lk/lk-10.html#ss10.2), not a block of code / formatted text. I've edited the post.

Comment: Presumably this is to accord with the long standing convention of naming preprocessor macros in ALLCAPS, and someone has just been lazy about the definitions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Syntax highlighting is handled using [Google Code Prettify.](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/) You'd have to report this problem to them (and abide by their decision regarding whether it's a problem or not; I'd say it was.)

EDIT: This seems to have been reported at least twice: see [bug 70](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/issues/detail?id=70) and [bug 114](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/issues/detail?id=114).

Comment: OK. It was in the bug list already, naturally. I voted for the bug. That was it.